# How to link a Swift Package Manager native module with a 3rd party framework on OSX

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

so its not clear at all how to specify a 3rdparty.framework in the link line of the SPM module map. Anyone have an example that works? And three cheers for amazingly well documented tools!

```
module DudeNative [system] {
   header "/Library/Frameworks/DudeNative.framework/Versions/A/Headers/DudeNative.h"
   link "DudeNative"
   export *
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A link-declaration specifies a library or framework against which a program should be linked if the enclosing module is imported in any translation unit in that program. In your case, you instruct the linker to link with `-lDudeNative` (for a Unix-style linker).

from man ld

```
-lx         This option tells the linker to search for libx.dylib or
            libx.a in the library search path.  If string x is of the
            form y.o, then that file is searched for in the same places,
            but without prepending `lib' or appending `.a' or `.dylib' to
            the filename.
```